# how to get smart quotes on org-mode export?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, typography, smart-quotes, smartypants

How do I get Emacs org-mode to create proper typographic marks when I export to HTML, including converting straight quotes to smart quotes ("curly quotes") and converting hyphens `---` to m-dashes `—`?

Comment: No, typing curly quotes by hand would be tedious and time-consuming.

Comment: Uhm, yeah, it's `Alt+{` on OS X and X11 US layout.  Pretty much as hard to type as a standard quote which is `Shift+'`.

Comment: You really want to contort your fingers every time you write `I'm` or `can't`?

Comment: Thousands of times per file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is now built into org-mode 8.x. To activate it, add the following to your Emacs configuration file:

```
(setq org-export-with-smart-quotes t)
```

It works for single quotes, double quotes, and apostrophes.

Source: @Ista

Answer (score 23):

```
#+LANGUAGE: de
#+OPTIONS: ':t
```

also does the right thing now

Comment: Thanks! Of course this also works with `#+LANGUAGE: en`

Answer (score 9):

This is only available in very recent versions of org-mode. If you are not already running the latest git version see http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#keeping-current-with-Org-mode-development for instructions on upgrading. Then `(setq org-export-with-smart-quotes t)` will do what you want with quotes, and m-dashes will also be exported correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, quotation marks appeared correctly. But apostrophes didn't appear as curly in words such as `didn't`. Is there a fix for that too?

Comment: I don't see a built in way of converting single quotes to curly apostrophes. You can write an export filter to do it yourself--see section 4.3 of http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-02/msg00067.html

Comment: Looks like this is one way in which Markdown (e.g. Brett Terpstra's Marked, which uses Smartypants) is superior to org-mode.

Comment: @PeterSalazar, to add, I think while `org-mode` has so many export options and so much functionality, it is thus less ideal for staying faithful to HTML. Markdown seems to be a closer approximation, though with less power behind it. For instance, org-mode can supply CSS style sheets for syntax highlighting (okay, there's a plug-in I bet for markdown).

Comment: Right. That said, converting single quotes to curly apostrophes on HTML export now works correctly by default in org-mode.

Answer (score -2):

A way to insure that smart quotes are entered in your org file is to insert the code at the following url into your init.el file.  Then type M-x smart-quotes-mode and your all set.

https://github.com/gareth-rees/smart-quotes/blob/master/smart-quotes.el

MNH

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/228805). Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue.